# Firebase Query in android app ,multiple order by need to work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase realtime DB in my app,I could not use multiple order by in my query.If i am not use that one,looping the data again and again.It leads my app run slow.So please help me how to do that.Otherwise how to get multiple items in single Query

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Query query = reference.child("issue").orderByChild("id").equalTo(0,1,3);
```

...Like,is it possible????

Comment: I think this is not possible. plz check https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

Comment: Ok,Then is there anyway how to use multiple order by in query,Please give some ideas

Comment: I think you need to create multiple queries and executed inside a loop.

Comment: Definitely it will slow down my application,how to resolve this problem

Comment: There will be a delay but no worries firebase cache control will handle this.

Comment: Thank you for your help.May i know details clearly about Firebase cache.

Comment: The Firebase Database can only order/filter on a single property. Sometimes it may be possible to combine the values you want to filter on in a single property. See my answer here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: Yes Frank,My exact question is...id->keyword:"bag,shoe,bata"...i stored...I need a query how to filter that keyword that contains bag...

Comment: productList->id1->keyword:"bag,bang,hook",
               ->product_id:"1",
               ->product_name:"My Product"

            ->id2->keyword:"hook",
               ->product_id:"2",
               ->product_name:"My Product1"....Please help me